# Wordpress localhost:3000 returns SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG with MAMP 6

Tags: wordpress, ssl, localhost, mamp

I upgraded MAMP to version 6 (not PRO).

When I launch my local wordpress project with npm start task, Firefox automatically redirects on https://localhost:3000 and I get the "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG" error.

How can I avoid SSL redirection for localhost:3000 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to phpmyadmin in MAMP, which is usually `localhost:(portnumber)/phpmyadmin`.

Find your wordpress database and then look for the `wp_options` table, or if your table is prefixed then look for `(prefix)_wp_options`.

Change the `site_url` and `home` options to http.